# Typescript get i value on a callback function when created

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can obtain the current value of i ?

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
   $(element).load("http://www.google.de", () => {
      console.log(i);
   }
}

Will return 2, 2, 2... How can i return 0, 1, 2 ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using a closure variable `i` from the outer function inside the ajax callback. Any changes made in the variable value will get reflected in the callback method.

One possible way is to use an anonymous function to provide a custom closure as given below

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
   (function(i){
   $(element).load("http://www.google.de", () => {
      console.log(i);
   }
   })(i)
}
```

Comment: know the reason, its a complete answer thanks for the solution